# Get git to not push certain files that are already being tracked

Tags: git

I've got local and remote repositories of the same site, but there are certain files that I want to keep seperate.

There's a config file and a .htaccess file on the local repo, but I want to keep different copies of these files on the remote. How can I get git to ignore these files when they're already being tracked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `assume-unchanged` flag.

Basically, try running the following command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

This will stop tracking any local changes to the file `filename`.

To undo the effect of above command, use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`

Comment: I've done that but it still seems to update them. Does that mean that it's assuming it's unchanged but then it sees a different version on the remote and so changes it back to the "unchanged" file?

Comment: You mean it(.htaccess file) gets updated to original value on doing a pull later on? IIRC, that is default behavior only when a new commit is made to the file. Will need to check that  and confirm.

Comment: When I push to the remote server, yes the .htaccess and config files get updated to the original values.

Comment: Hmm, your htacces file should be committed corresponding to the values you want on remote. Then, the local copy should have changes specific to your enviroment, and this file should be assumed unchanged. Is that what you do and still face issues?

Comment: Ah, ok, sorted now. I had changed the remote files outside git, so it was still seeing a difference between the "unchaged" files and the remote. So I did as you say, commit the values that I want on the remote, then assume unchanged. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The proper git workflow would be to use branches. For example, keep your master branch in-sync with the remote and create a branch "local" for changes to the config and .htaccess files.

With this setup you would do most of your work in master, then when you want to test stuff locally you would first do

```
git checkout local
git merge master
```

The advantage of this approach is that if the config or .htaccess files change on the remote, it should show up as a merge conflict with the local branch (which is good, because maybe the new changes should be added to your local config).